# How to connect the nested VM to directly from the local host machine using ip?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have ec2 instance . This ec2 instance has 3 nested Ubuntu running in it . in order to connect to this instance i have to connect to ec2 instance and then ssh into the nested ubuntu machine .

Is there a way in which i can ssh or connect to this nested machine directly from my local host pc .

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have machine A with IP A_ip and user A_user, machine B with IP B_ip and user as B_user and machine C with IP C_ip and user C_user then simply run this command :-

`ssh -J A_user@A_ip B_user@B_ip C_user@C_ip`

From `man-ssh`

```
-J [user@]host[:port]
    Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to
    the jump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the
    ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be
    specified separated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to
    specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! it worked for ssh . My machine A have ip of 10.55.1.12 and My machine B have ip of 10.55.1.234  . With the technique mentioned above i am able to login . My machine B is running a Mysql server . what would be my host name so that i get connected to machine B mysql server directly